# python loop a list of class objects

Tags: python

I have class:

```
class Services:
    
    def __init__(self,a1,b1):
        self.a1 = a1
        self.b1 = b1
        
        
    def do_something(self):
        print('hello')
        
        

obj1 = Services('aaa','bbb')
obj2 = Services('aaa1','bbb1')

objlist =['obj1','obj2']

for i in objlist:
    i.do_something()
```

Is is possible to loop objects and call class methods for multiple objects?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it? Why are you adding strings to your list of objects instead of objects themselves?

Comment: List should be `[obj1,obj2]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through a list of objects and call their methods. However, in your list, you need to store the objects and not strings. Modified code:

```
#Create your class
class Services:
    
    def __init__(self,a1,b1):
        self.a1 = a1
        self.b1 = b1      
        
    def do_something(self):
        print('hello')
        
#Create two objects
obj1 = Services('aaa','bbb')
obj2 = Services('aaa1','bbb1')

#Create a list of objects
objlist = [obj1,obj2]

#Loop through the list of objects and call their method
for obj in objlist:
    obj.do_something()
```

Output:

```
hello
hello
```